# HFS+ encrypted external could not mount or not be repaired - OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, mount

I have a serious problem with my TimeMachine external 8TB Seagate.
It has been used as my TimeMachine disk. Did a full backup, installed lastest OS X from scratch and the external disk will no longer mount.
My pictures are on this disk. Here are the commands I have run to try and fix this.
I don't want to use DiskWarrior or any other Thirdparty software.

```
diskutil list
  /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         124.7 GB   disk0s2
      3:       Microsoft Basic Data DEBIAN                  124.5 GB   disk0s3
      4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4

  /dev/disk1 (synthesized):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +124.7 GB   disk1
                                    Physical Store disk0s2
      1:                APFS Volume OSX                     21.4 GB    disk1s1
      2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.9 MB    disk1s2
      3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.0 MB   disk1s3
      4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s4

  /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk2
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
      2:          Apple_CoreStorage Seagate                 8.0 TB     disk2s2
      3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3

  /dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:                  Apple_HFS Seagate                +8.0 TB     disk3
                                    Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                    784988D6-B233-4BFC-AB1C-45EA7FF24640
                                    Unencrypted
```

```
sudo fsck_hfs -l /dev/disk3
  ** /dev/rdisk3 (NO WRITE)
      Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
  ** Performing live verification.
  ** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
      The volume name is Seagate
  ** Checking extents overflow file.
      Invalid leaf record count
      (It should be 190 instead of 192)
  ** Checking catalog file.
      Invalid sibling link
  (4, 318227)
  ** The volume Seagate was found corrupt and needs to be repaired.
```

```
sudo fsck_hfs -r
  ** /dev/rdisk3
      Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
  ** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
      The volume name is Seagate
  ** Checking extents overflow file.
      Invalid leaf record count
      (It should be 190 instead of 192)
  ** Checking catalog file.
  ** Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
  ** The volume Seagate could not be repaired.
```

Comment: tbh, on an HFS+ drive, DiskWarrior would be my go-to option, not my last resort.

Comment: Hate to sound like a broken record but if disk utility (EG built-in disk repair functions) don't work then you have two choices, reformat the drive or try a 3rd party disk utility.

Comment: But I have no guarantee that DiskWarrior will fix it, do I? Hate to spend much money on something that  perhaps fix it.

Comment: DiskWarrior is simply the single best tool there is for this kind of damage, nothing else comes close. Of course there is no guarantee it will fix it, but at least it won't break it further. It won't actually deploy any fix until you tell it to. You get the chance to compare the fix to the original before committing. If it can't fix it, then you need to look at the range of file recovery software instead, or pay a recovery company. By comparison, DW is the cheap first option.